# Opencart 2.3 - showing discount in featured extension

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

I am new to Opencart and I am trying to display the quantity discount in the featured products - without success. I am using Opencart 2.3. Basically, what I would like to achieve is to pass the variables `quantity` and `price` from the controller file `featured.php` to the view file `featured.tpl`.

Here is what I have tried:

1) In the file `/catalog/controller/extension/module/featured.php` after the `$product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);` I added the following code:

```
$discounts = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductDiscounts($product_id);

$data['discounts'][] = array();

foreach ($discounts as $discount) {
    $data['discounts'][] = array(
'quantity' => $discount['quantity'],
'price' => $discount['price']
);
}
```

2) In the file `/catalog/view/theme/default/template/extension/module/featured.tpl` I added the following code:

```
<?php foreach ($discounts as $discount) { ?>
<span>
<?php echo sprintf($text_discount, $discount['quantity'], $discount['price']); ?>
</span><br>
<?php } ?>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

I have tried several other variations of code (e.g. the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540081/why-opencart-is-not-passing-variable-from-module-to-view-file)), but no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to catalog\language\en-gb\extension\module\featured.php
Add following code:

```
$_['text_discount']            = ' or more ';
```

Go to catalog\controller\extension\module\featured.php
Find following lines of code:

```
$data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');
```

Add following lines of code:

```
$data['text_discount'] = $this->language->get('text_discount');
```

Find following lines of code:

```
foreach ($products as $product_id) {
   $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);
```

Add following lines of code:

```
$discounts = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductDiscounts($product_id);

            $product_info['discounts'] = array();

            foreach ($discounts as $discount) {
                $product_info['discounts'][] = array(
                    'quantity' => $discount['quantity'],
                    'price'    => $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($discount['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency'])
                );
            }
```

Find following lines of code:

```
$data['products'][] = array(
                    'product_id' => $product_info['product_id'],
```

Just below it Add following lines of code:

```
'discounts'=>$product_info['discounts'],
```

Now go to catalog\view\theme\YOUR_ACTIVE_THEME\template\extension\module\featured.tpl

Find following lines of code:

```
 <div class="button-group">
            <button type="button" onclick="cart.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');">
```

Add above it or where ever you want to show but need to inside the product array:

```
<?php if ($product['discounts']) { ?>
        <ul>
            <hr>
            <?php foreach ($product['discounts'] as $discount) { ?>
            <li><?php echo $discount['quantity']; ?><?php echo $text_discount; ?><?php echo $discount['price']; ?></li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
        <?php } ?>
```

You can download the ocmod at [Show Discounts at featured module Ocmod OpenCart 2.3.02](https://webocreation.com/blog/show-discounts-featured-module-opencart-2-3)

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot! You've saved me a lot of work :)